# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have used SQLalchemy in python3 to connect to local MySQL.
However, I got such error: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

The password is the same as in MySQL workbench, that is "root", I do not know why I got this error.

My code:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost/db?host=localhost?port=3308", echo=True)


with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    book_df.to_sql(name='test', con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: Does `create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3308/db', echo=True)` work?

Comment: yes, It worked, thanks. Not sure why my code not working

Comment: sqlalchemy expects the url to be in the form `database+driver://user:password@host:port/databasename`; passing the port etc as query arguments is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered at the top, but if you want connect to RDS and if you have special characters in your password like "@" be sure to use **urllib.parse.quote** or else you will encounter the same error.

```
import urllib

user = "user"
password = urllib.parse.quote("p@ssword")
endpoint = "rds_endpoint"
port = "port"
db = "db_name"
engine = create_engine(f"mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@{endpoint}:{port}/{db}", echo=True)
```